# TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing python2 working but py3 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python2 wotking but py3 not working

```
hashlib.sha256(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "", each_user["Merchandiser"]).lower()[
                                           :4].capitalize() + "@123").hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the string before you call hexdigest.

Try the following:

```
import hashlib

hashlib.sha256(
    (
        re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "", each_user["Merchandiser"]
              ).lower()[:4].capitalize() + "@123"
    ).encode("utf-8")
).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

what type is 'each_user' here?

I think your need to encode sha256 argument

```
hashlib.sha256((re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "", each_user["Merchandiser"]).lower()[:4].capitalize() + "@123").encode())
```

if

```
each_user["Merchandiser"]
```

is a str